# How do I find a pattern with several wildcard strings in a suffix tree?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, suffix-tree

Let's say that I got a suffix tree ST(T) and a pattern S<sub>1</sub> * S<sub>2</sub> ... * S<sub>k</sub>, whereas * represents any string out of the same alphabet as the strings S<sub>1</sub>,...,S<sub>k</sub>.

How do I find the pattern  using the indexes of the leaf nodes?

My idea for 2 strings S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub> would be to put every occurence of S<sub>1</sub> and S<sub>2</sub> into integer lists a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub> and check if any integer in a<sub>2</sub> is greater or equal than any integer in a<sub>1</sub> + s<sub>1</sub>.length.

Am I on the right track? And is it a similar method for k strings?

Comment: You don't need all of `a1` and `a2` - just the first value of `a1` and the smallest value of `a2` that is large enough.  Repeat for `a3` and so on.  If you get to `ak` then you have your answer.  (Assuming that the string only has characters from the right alphabet.  If it doesn't, then you will need to work harder...)